# JavaScript : Split string using function and returning it

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Tried several thinks but the function doesn't work/return properly (The html code is okay)

```
var divResult = document.getElementById("divResult");
var naam;

function splitsen(naam){
    var res = naam.split(" ");
    document.write(res[0]);
    var voornaam = res[0];
    var achternaam = res[1];
    var tnaam = [voornaam, achternaam];
return tnaam;
}

naam = parseInt(prompt("Geef je voornaam en achternaam in gescheiden met een spatie"));

var voornaam = splitsen(naam)[0];
var achternaam = splitsen(naam)[1];
divResult.innerHTML = "oefening 8";
divResult.innerHTML += "Voornaam: " + voornaam;
divResult.innerHTML += "Achternaam" + achternaam;
divResult.innerHTML += "Email: " + voornaam + "." + achternaam + "@student.arteveldehs.be";
```

Comment: well your function work it return 2 words in an array

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt('My Name');` returns `NaN`.

Remove the `parseInt()`, and just keep it as:

```
var naam = prompt('Input your name seperated by a space.');
```

Comment: No problem. If you would accept my answer, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I could spot 2 problems in your code:

1-**The parameter name to your function is the same name as that of a global variable**. It is probable that any references to 'naam' in your function use the global variable instead of what you pass. Regardless, don't do that.

2-**`parseInt` will take a string and extract an integer out of it and returns a `number`**. `number` types doesn't have the `split()` method and you probably wanted a string containing the name.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz What are you talking about?

Comment: Nevermind my first comment. What I meant to say is that the parameter name can be the same as the global variable. It won't matter.

Comment: Yes, but still. That can cause ambiguity from a developer's point of view.

Comment: He doesn't even need a parameter. `naam` is a global, and therefore accessible in the function without it being passed in.

Comment: So, I see you agree using a global variable's name for a function parameter is bad.

Comment: Nope. I think it's perfectly fine as long as you understand that you're losing access to the original global.

Comment: Perfectly fine? Personally, I'd like to know whether I am referring to a global variable or a parameter variable without having to look at a function's parameter list for the occurrence of a global variable name.